# PCA reconstruction error of Sinusoids

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I'm using PCA to reconstruct a pair of sinusoidal signals. The second signal differs from the first in that its frequency is higher but I've kept the variance of the signals the same. I want to find out why the reconstruction error is higher for the higher frequency signal when using PCA to reconstruct it even though the variance is the same?

Also why would the reconstruction error for a white noise signal be higher when its variance is the same as the sinusoids?

I've also included a code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

def genSine(A,f0,fs,dur):    
    t = np.arange(dur)
    sinusoid = A*np.sin(2*np.pi*t*(f0/fs))
    return sinusoid

def pca_reconstruction(X):
    pca = PCA(n_components = 1)
    latent=pca.fit_transform(X)
    X_projected = pca.inverse_transform(latent)
    return np.sum((X_projected-X)**2)

amplitude=1.415
f0=1
fs=100

duration=20480

df1 = genSine(amplitude,f0,fs,duration)
X1=np.reshape(df1,(2048,10))
print(pca_reconstruction(X1))

fs2=50 #higher frequency sinusoid

df2 = genSine(amplitude,f0,fs2,duration)
X2=np.reshape(df2,(2048,10))
print(pca_reconstruction(X2))

df3 = np.random.normal(scale=1, size=20480)
X3=np.reshape(df3,(2048,10))
print(pca_reconstruction(X3))

#variance=1
#Reconstruction Error:
#sinusoid: 654.8819222758402, sinusoid increasing frequency: 2473.0607892191633
#white noise: 18229.17924740033
```

Comment: I see from the reshaping commands that you are not simply considering the PCA of sinusoids. Can you explain the motivation for reshaping the data in this way?

Comment: Are you trying to use [Taken's embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takens%27s_theorem) on a 1-dimensional manifold?

Comment: @Galen Im trying to bottleneck the information in the sinusoid so that PCA doesn’t perfectly reconstruct it. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Galen No, Im not trying to use that theorem.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Just choosing a space transformed from a sinusoidal such that it has non-zero reconstruction error does not have a clear purpose to me.

Comment: For what it is worth, the parametric curve $(t, \sin t )$ will also be imperfectly compressible with (linear) PCA projecting down to 1D. `t = np.arange(duration); X = np.zeros((len(t), 2)); X[:,0] = t; X[:,1] = df1; pca_reconstruction(X)`